# Wagtail: Searching page and parent with backend db

Tags: wagtail-search

I am new to Wagtail/Django. Getting start was quite easy and I got my application up and running quite easily. However I ran into a problem when I was searcing. The application is quite small and I would like to use the backend db (or MSSQL). 
I have search all around but suprisingly not managed to find  solution. Hope to get one her :-)

I have a page with inline elements. Simplified below

```
class BlockPage(Page):
    content = RichTextField()

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('content'),
        InlinePanel('rel_page_blocks', label="Markup blocks"),
    ]

    search_fields = [
        index.SearchField('content', partial_match=True),  
        index.RelatedFields('rel_page_blocks', [
            index.SearchField('block_content', partial_match=True),
        ]),
        index.FilterField('live'),
    ]
```

The inline panel is defined like this

```
class Blocks(index.Indexed, Orderable):
    page = ParentalKey(BlockPage, related_name='rel_page_blocks')
    block_content = RichTextField()

    panels = [
        FieldPanel('block_content'),
   ]
```

So far so good. Now I would like to search the page with its inline Blocks. I have successfully searched the page but the **Blocks** are not searched. I know that this issue is solved using Elastic search but it is not an option for me.

Her is the **views.py**

```
def search(request):
    search_query = request.GET.get('query', None)
    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)

    # Search
    if search_query:
        blocks_results = BlockPage.objects.live().search(search_query)     
        blocks_result_ids = [p.page_ptr.id for p in blocks_results]

# I get a result using this but I would like it to be attached to the 
# parent so when viewing the result I can refere/show the parent BlockPage
# The question is how to attach "r" to the parent result?  
 r = get_search_backend().search(search_query, Blocks)

    page_ids = blocks_result_ids + **other page ids**
    search_results = Page.objects.filter(id__in=page_ids)        

    query = Query.get(search_query)
    # Record hit
    query.add_hit()
else:
    search_results = Page.objects.none()

return render(request, 'search/search.html', {
    'search_query': search_query,
    'search_results': search_results,
})
```

Any hint would be greatly appreciated. I am a only a couple of days old here so please bear that in mind if you have a solution.